# Split array of characters into alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric ones

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm just a student and I want to know about this array in c++.

How can I display all alphanumeric chars inputted on array `k` to array `n`
and all non-alphanumeric on array `t`?

This what I made, and I don't know what's next

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
   char k[8], n[8], t[8];

   int ctr, nctr, tctr;

   for(ctr=0; ctr<8; ctr++){ 
     cout << "Input 1st Element ";

     cin >> k[ctr];  
     if (isalnum(k[ctr]))
```

Comment: I'm confused... but err since your a student, could you post a link or soemthing to the actual assignment so that I could read that and give you a better answer?

Comment: Which part do you need help with, the `if-then-else` structure or putting something into an array?

Comment: Can you give an example input and output?

Comment: It looks like you know how to use `cin` to read characters, how to use `isalnum` to find alphanumerics, and how to use a loop to iterate over an array. You'll need `cout` to display them, `!isalnum` to find non-alphanumerics, and a couple more loops.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The code won't get `enter`, since `>>` skips over white space. The only problem is if you want to include spaces in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

        char k[8], n[8], t[8];

        strcpy(k,"--------");
        strcpy(n,"--------");
        strcpy(t,"--------");

    for (int pos = 0, tcntr = 0, ncntr =0; pos < 8; pos++) {
            cout<<"Input your char < : ";
            cin>>k[pos];

                if (isalnum(k[pos])) {
                        n[ncntr] = k[pos];
                        ncntr++;
                } else {

                        t[tcntr] = k[pos];
                        tcntr++;
                }
        }

        cout<<"Alpha numernic chars ::"<<n<<endl;
        cout<<"Non Aplha numberic chars ::"<<t<<endl;
}


Input your char < : 3
Input your char < : ^ 
Input your char < : d 
Input your char < : &
Input your char < : f
Input your char < : 1
Input your char < : 7
Input your char < : 1
Alpha numernic chars ::3df171--
Non Aplha numberic chars ::^&------
```

Comment: kindly see the link bellow to see what is the exact output
tnx.. hope you can help me

http://i893.photobucket.com/albums/ac135/melwinjay/ass.jpg

Comment: sir your answer is correct but i think there's a problem on it
when i enter 1 - 9 on array k it prints an alphanumeric chars and a non-alphanumeric char like this...................................

Alphanumeric chars :: 1234567812345678x "
Non Alpha numeric chars ::d
press any key to continue . . .

Comment: check now i have adapted and corrected my mistake. Kindly vote up if you found this answer useful.

Comment: the "-" on the picture that i posted means it is a blank sir..
btw... if you can fixed it again sir thank you so much :p

Comment: again sir it doubles the answer. when i enter 1-8 it gives me Alpha numeric chars : 1234567812345678 and a Non Alpha Numeric chars -----------1234567812345678

Comment: see the link to see what i mean http://i893.photobucket.com/albums/ac135/melwinjay/ass2.jpg

Comment: hint '\0' this is left as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I display all alphanumeric chars inputted on array k to array n and all non-alphanumeric on array t?

I assume by "display" you mean "copy"? Just use a conditional:

```
int ctr, nctr = 0, tctr = 0;   // note how I explicitly set the counters to 0

for (ctr = 0; ctr < 8; ctr++)
{ 
    cout << "Input Element " << ctr << ": ";

    cin >> k[ctr];  
    if (isalnum(k[ctr]))
    {
        n[nctr++] = k[ctr];
    }
    else
    {
        t[tctr++] = k[ctr];
    }
}
```

If that's not what you wanted, please provide more information.

Comment: Enter an Element : 1

Enter an Element : @

Enter an Element : 3

Enter an Element : #

Enter an Element : 5

Enter an Element : %

Enter an Element : 7

Enter an Element : 8


Alphanumeric Character :

1    3    5    7    8    -     -     -



Non-Alphanumeric :


@    #    %    -    -    -    -    -


The output should be like that..


if the users enter an alphanumeric char on array k
all the alphanumeric chars on that array k should be copied on
array n and the rest that are non-alpha numeric will be on array t

Comment: kindly see the link bellow to see what is the exact output tnx.. hope you can help me 
i893.photobucket.com/albums/ac135/melwinjay/ass.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If it is allowed to use STL, this is when `partition_copy` is the best solution. You can split array `k` into two arrays `n` and `t` by checking given predicate (whether char is alphanumeric in your case). Like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  const size_t len = 8;
  char k[len], n[len], t[len];

  // Input your data...

  // Copy all alphanumeric chars in n and non-alphanumeric to t
  partition_copy(k, k + len, n, t, isalnum);
}
```

Comment: it gives me this error 'partition_copy' undeclared (first use this function)

Comment: What compiler do you use? In case of Visual Studio, only `partition` function is present before MSVC2010. It does the same thing, but inplace. Check MSDN.

Comment: Seems like it is just not implemented in Dev C++. By the way, if you don't have explicit requirement to sotre input in array and then split it, it would be easier to check chars as they are inputed and to push them to corresponding array (n or t). Again, if you are allowed to use STL, you can declare it as `vector<char> n, t` and use `push_back()` to add characters.